# My unity 3d fps movement is going through walls and they all have colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the problem I am having is when I run full speed (i.e. pressing a and w and looking 45 degrees to the right it doesn't use .normalized on purpose) into a wall or anything else it allows the player to go through it, so my code is

```
Vector3 m_Input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
Vector3 moveDirection = m_Input;
moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveDirection * moveSpeed);
```

and `moveSpeed` is set to `0.2`. I have checked and all of the colliders are not triggers. any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off do double check

- All your colliders & rigidbody are 3d
- Everything is on the same layer (or your layers are set to interact with each other)
- Your rigidbody is attached to the same game object as your collider

However, it seems that your issue is that your `rigidbody` is set to be [kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) (as [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) is intended to be used by kinematic rigidbody's only)

If your `rigidbody` is set to `kinematic` then no forces (such as collider normal forces) will be applied to your object, so it will be able to pass through walls.

### Solution

The easiest way to avoid this is by making sure your rigidbody is set to non-kinematic, and moving it via [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

Something similar to:

```
Vector3 m_Input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, 
Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
Vector3 moveDirection = m_Input;
moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

rb.velocity = (moveDirection * moveSpeed);
```

This should move your character according to physics and allow for the correct interactions with colliders.

---

Also, you should be aware if you ever do want to move a rigidbody like that, you should be sure to do so in `FixedUpdate` and scale movement by `Time.FixedDeltaTime`.

Comment: ah ok thank you ill test it now and yeah I am doing it in fixedupdate already

Comment: and also is kinematic was off

Comment: and now i have another problem

Comment: @JaiSloper if kinematic was off then you probably shouldn't have moved it by `MovePosition` as the docs state this is for kinematic only. If you have another problem then just open another question :)

Answer (score 0):

now the jump is broken this is the full script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPSMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public GameObject cam;

    Vector2 rotation = Vector2.zero;
    public float sensitivity = 10f;
    public string xAxis = "Mouse X";
    public string yAxis = "Mouse Y";

    public float OmoveSpeed;
    public float SprintSpeed;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpVar;

    public bool Grounded = false;

    public Vector3 slideScale;
    public Vector3 normalScale;
    public Vector3 dir;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        moveSpeed = OmoveSpeed;
        slideScale = new Vector3(1, 0.5f, 1);
        normalScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        dir = rb.velocity;

        // Should be cross platform movement
        Vector3 m_Input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        Vector3 moveDirection = m_Input;
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        rb.velocity = (moveDirection * moveSpeed);

        // Sprinting
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            moveSpeed = SprintSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            moveSpeed = OmoveSpeed;
        }

        // Jumping
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Grounded)
            {
                rb.velocity += new Vector3(0, jumpVar, 0);
                Grounded = false;
            }
        }

        // TO-DO: Sliding

        // Camera Rotation
        rotation.x += Input.GetAxis(xAxis) * sensitivity;
        rotation.y += Input.GetAxis(yAxis) * sensitivity;
        rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -90, 90);
        var xQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up);
        var yQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.y, Vector3.left);

        transform.localRotation = xQuat;
        cam.transform.localRotation = yQuat;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Grounded = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        Grounded = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a further problem then the anwers really isnt the place to put it, i'd delete this and just open a new question. You can even link to this question if you feel it needed

Comment: Ah ok thank this is the new question if you wanna have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/71447156/16729686